# Docker inspect: Select field that has forward slash using jq

Tags: bash, docker, jq

```
# docker inspect blah | jq '.[] | .NetworkSettings.Ports'
{
    "22/tcp": [
     {
       "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
       "HostPort": "32776"
     }
    ]
}
```

How the heck do I get the `HostPort` value? I tried the following but that failed.

```
# docker inspect blah | jq '.[] | .NetworkSettings.Ports.22\/tcp.HostPort'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not :

```
docker inspect  --format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort }}' blah
```

this will eliminate the needs of another tool.

Answer (score 3):

`jq` supports double quotes for keys with special characters:

```
jq '."22/tcp".HostPort'
```

edit: this is mentioned in [the docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example2), which also mention that you can add brackets to help with readability, if you want:

```
jq '.["22/tcp"].HostPort'
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is close but needs to add a bracket to work correctly.

`jq '."22/tcp"[].HostPort'`